# Como funciona a sessão por requisição?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, design-pattern

Surgiu uma ideia no meio dos desenvolvedores de utilizar o padrão de *Session per request* - Sessão por requisição.

Pesquisando sobre o assunto, encontrei alguns topicos no SO que em geral diziam que a indicação era para *frameworks* ORM.

**Pequeno exemplo prático**

```
//GET Controller/Teste

public ActionResult Teste()
{
     //abrir conexão com o banco

     var model = new TesteViewModel 
                 {
                      ListaClientes = _servicoCliente.ObterClientes(),
                      ListaProdutos = _servicoProduto.ObterProdutos()
                 };

     //fechar conexão com o banco
     return View(model);
}
```

**Sem o *session per request*:**

```
//GET Controller/Teste

public ActionResult Teste()
{
  var model = new TesteViewModel 
    {
       ListaClientes = _servicoCliente.ObterClientes(), // Abro e fecho a conexão com o banco no inicio e fim do método, respectivamente.
       ListaProdutos = _servicoProduto.ObterProdutos() // Abro e fecho a conexão com o banco no inicio e fim do método, respectivamente.
    };
  return View(model);
}
```

**Perguntas:**

1. Para contextualizar, como consiste a sessão por requisição?
2. É uma boa solução?
3. Qual seria a melhor forma de implementação? Abrir a conexão via web mesmo?
4. É recomendado em projetos com consultas/operações complexas?
5. Existe chance de dar problema de concorrência quando há operações/transações envolvidas?

Comment: As perguntas 2, 3 e 4 dão muita margem pra opinião.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Para contextualizar, como consiste a sessão por requisição?

Para fazer uma requisição a uma base de dados é necessário abrir um ligação com essa mesma base de dados.

Pode considerar que existe uma sessão enquanto esta ligação estiver aberta. Ou seja, você pode fazer as requisições que quiser enquanto não fechar a sua ligação (durante a duração da sessão).

Assim, o conceito de "sessão por requisição" suporta a ideologia que deve somente fazer uma requisição á base de dados, por cada vez que estabelecer a ligação.

> 2. É uma boa solução?

Resposta 1

Depende da sua aplicação, pelo menos esta é a resposta que todos os utilizadores aqui aceitariam sem qualquer controvérsia.

Resposta 2

Em principio não. Na minha perspetiva é muito melhor estabelecer uma sessão por cada processo de negócio. O motivo é simples. Pode ser só especulação, mas eu diria que grande parte das aplicações necessitam de realizar possessos atómicos, utilizando por exemplo transações (que fazem um ou mais pedidos á base de dados).

Eu tive a testar se era possível fazer várias operações dentro duma transação em ligações diferentes e isso não deu certo. Mesmo que desse não faria sentido fazer um processo aos bocados.

> Qual seria a melhor forma de implementação? Abrir a conexão via web mesmo?

Não sei do que está a falar, da aplicação web ou da base de dados? O protocolo de comunicação com base de dados mais comum é eventualmente o TCP, também é comum o uso de named pipes.

> É recomendado em projetos com consultas/operações complexas?

Acho que já expliquei como eu faria na minha segunda resposta á pergunta 2.

> Existe chance de dar problema de concorrência quando há operações/transações envolvidas?

Pois este é exatamente um dos problemas que eu mencionei.

---

Queria acrescentar que o exemplo dado pode ainda ter um outro problema. O AP não deu detalhes sobre o esquema de tabelas, por isso não é possível confirmar. Mas imaginando que cada cliente tem uma lista de produtos então teria menor custo trazer os dois ao mesmo tempo (com uma operação de join, isto poderia ser feito numa requisição e consequentemente numa ligação á base de dados)

Comment: Então, o exemplo com as listas foi meramente "ilustrativo". Nesse exemplo, foram apenas duas consultas no banco. E no caso de 10 consultas? Ir 10 vezes no banco ou ir uma só?

Comment: @MarllonNasser Depende do processo que quiser fazer. Na minha carreira profissional nunca encontrei nenhum processo que voce consiga fazer com apenas numa requisicao em vez de fazer em 10. No máximo já consegui juntar 3 ou 4 requisicoes numa só. Em geral menos costuma ser melhor, mas se o volume de dados for grande tem que arranjar estratégias como batching ou paginacao.